# Segmentation Fault: C++ sort an string vector with lambda comparator

Tags: c++, string, sorting, lambda

```
int main() {
    vector<string> v(100, "0");
    auto comp = [](const string& first, const string& second)->bool {
        return first.compare(second) <= 0;
    };
    sort(v.begin(), v.end(), comp);
    for(auto s : v) {
        cout<<s<<endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Above c++ code got segmentation fault with g++ v4.9.2. it's so wired. who know what's going on?

Comment: The right tool to solve such problems is your debugger. You should step through your code line-by-line *before* asking on Stack Overflow. For more help, please read [How to debug small programs (by Eric Lippert)](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/). At a minimum, you should \[edit] your question to include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) example that reproduces your problem, along with the observations you made in the debugger.

Comment: I cannot debug into the sort function, so i'm here...but i should read the comments of sort function carefully.

Comment: Why you can't debug? Elaborate please.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Your comparison function is not a valid. It fails both at irreflexivity (*comp(x, x) should never be true*) and asymmetry (*if comp(x, y) is true, then comp(y, x) must be false*), both of which are part of the [strict weak ordering](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/concept/Compare) which `std::sort` requires for its comparator. `operator<` or `operator>` satisfy this requirement. But `operator<=` and `operator>=` do not.

If you change your comparison function to this:

```
auto comp = [](const string& first, const string& second)->bool {
    return first.compare(second) < 0;
};
```

It will work. Of course, that is functionally identical to what you get as the default, so you could just do this:

```
sort(v.begin(), v.end());
```